# What is a subtle way to imply that a ship is sinking?

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests

I require a phrase that implies that a ship is sinking without explicitly stating so.

Comment: A rat swam past the porthole.

Comment: ... closely followed by the ship's cat.

Comment: *Attention* Titanic *passengers. We have paused momentarily to take on some ice.*

Comment: The ship's horn gurgled into the night.

Comment: Please read the [phrase-request tag info](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/phrase-requests/info) and particularly the checklist at the end. Otherwise this is simply a guessing game or a beauty contest.

Comment: Riding low in the water.

Comment: The captain gave the command to man the life boats.

Comment: Holed below the waterline

Comment: Please note that either your ship is sinking without explicitly "stating that" or your ship is sinking without explicitly "saying so." Is that difference clear?

Comment: @Andrew Leach is wholly right…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ship is ***listing***.  From [Sea Talk Nautical Dictionary](http://www.seatalk.info/cgi-bin/nautical-marine-sailing-dictionary/db.cgi?db=db&uid=default&FirstLetter=l&sb=Term&view_records=View+Records&nh=5)

Term: list (n) 
Definition: The extent of leaning to one side of a ship that is damaged or loaded improperly.

If a ship is sinking, it is extremely unlikely that it will sink straight down without listing.  Of course, a ship may list without subsequently sinking.

> Why is the ship listing?  Why are my feet wet?

This is unambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

How about “we might end up sleeping with the fishes tonight”?

The phrase [*sleep with the fishes*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sleep_with_the_fishes) means to be dead underwater. It’s associated with the film *The Godfather*, but similar phrases can be found in The Iliad and Moby Dick.